# Creating dictionary. Error invalid use of Me keyword

Tags: vba, excel

this is my code. I have column C that has duplicate names and column B that has unique IDs I need to find which unique IDs match with what names and send an email to the names and paste the unique IDs in the email. I am getting an error on the first Me.Cells.

Sub sendEmails()

```
Dim dict_emails As Scripting.dictionary
Set dict_emails = New Scripting.dictionary
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMailMessage As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim row As Range
Dim table As ListObject
Dim row_index As Long
Dim strEmail As String
Dim strExeptionID As String

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("New 0-30").Select

Set table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("New_030_Table")

For row_index = 1 To table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    strEmail = table.DataBodyRange(row_index, 3).Value
    strExceptionID = table.DataBodyRange(row_index, 2).Value

    If Not dict_emails.Exists(strEmail) Then
        ' first time we have seen this name
        dict_emails.Add strEmail, strExceptionID
    Else
        dict_emails(strEmail) = dict_emails(strEmail) & vbCrLf & strExceptionID
    End If
Next

Dim var_key As Variant
For Each var_key In dict_emails.Keys
Set objMailMessage = objOutlook.CreateItem(0) ' create new mail
    With objMailMessage
        .To = "" & var_key
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Exceptions Set to Expire in Less Than 30 Days"
        .Body = "You have the following exceptions set to expire: " & vbCrLf & dict_emails(var_key)
        .Save ' save as draft
    End With
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: `Me` will work if your code is in a sheet module (where it will refer to the containing worksheet), but not in a regular module. `Me` is a way for object code to refer to "itself" (the object instance which it's running in)  Code in a regular module isn't in that kind of environment (ie it's not running in an object instance)

Comment: You also haven't defined the variable `Row` anywhere.  (Unless, perhaps, you have defined it with module or project level scope but not included that part of your code in the question?)

Answer (score 3):

I was in same issue and I foung solution !! 
but anyone will not believe in reference list "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"  set priority to top 3rd. and it will start working and error will be gone.